# Python pass only parameters which are not None to a function

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, nonetype

I have a function with four parameters `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` as shown below.

```
def myfunc(a=None,b=None,c=None,d=None):
    
    if <check which are not None>:
        myfunc2(<pass those which are not None>)
```

I need to call another function `myfunc2` inside this function but with only those parameters which the user has passed in `myfunc`. For example, if the user passes values for `a` and `d` in `myfunc`, then I need to call `myfunc2` as:

```
myfunc2(a=a, d=d)
```

Is there a simple way to do this rather than write `if` cases for all possible combinations of `a,b,c,d`?

Comment: Is `myfunc2` defaulting arguments to something other than `None`? Otherwise this wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 13):

You could use dict comprehension to create a dictionary with the not none params and pass it to `myfunc2` through unpacking.

```python
def myfunc(a=None,b=None,c=None,d=None):
    params = {
        "a": a,
        "b": b,
        "c": c,
        "d": d,
    }

    not_none_params = {k:v for k, v in params.items() if v is not None}
    myfunc2(**not_none_params)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
    myfunc2(**{k:v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None})
```

If you want to preserve the function's call signature, with the 4 specified default arguments, you can do this:

```
def myfunc(a=None, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    def f(**kwargs):
        return myfunc2(**{k:v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None})
    return f(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)
```

Comment: Not useful IMO. If OP has default arguments which default to `None`. And your function takes `**kwargs` why would anyone pass something like this `myfunc(a=2, b=None, c=None, d=3)`?? The whole point of the question is OP would pass `myfunc(a=2, d=3)`

Comment: To make my point clear let's assume OP would set some variables depending `None` /default variables. If the function definition is `myfunc(**kwargs)`, then it has no default values. So, the workaround would be `myfunc(a=1, b=None, c=None, d=2)`. Doesn't it defeat the purpose of default arguments?

Comment: The question gave a function where all the default values are, in fact, None.  He doesn't want to pass any variables that are None.  So the default values will not be passed to the second function anyway.  But I see your point, the two functions (his and mine) are in fact different.